# Better way to select products that are related to ALL of the categories?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select products that are related to ALL of the categories, that has been "handed" to me.

The products are in the Product table and the relation to the categories are in the ProductCategoryRelation table.

The below code works, but I am not sure it is the fastest way to do it.

The 1,2,3 numbers are the category IDs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product
WHERE (
    SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM ProductCategoryRelation 
    WHERE ProductCategoryRelation.CategoryId IN (1,2,3) 
        AND ProductCategoryRelation.ProductId = Product.ProductId
    ) = 3
```

Comment: When you say "handed to me", what do you mean?  Does someone verbally tell you the categories?

Comment: @Max I think he means he inherited the query.

Comment: That's what I thought at first; then I figured I'd ask instead of assume.  Just in case there is some process he can use in query.  Trying to get the whole picture.

Comment: A similar question at SO, with a lot (more than 10) ways to achieve this: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation) (and some performance tests for Postgres)

Comment: @MaxVernon Right that might have sounded a bit strange :) By "handed" I mean what category ID's are sent via a webservice from a frontend application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you, should perform better.

```
WITH CTE_ProductCount AS
(
    SELECT PC.ProductID
        , COUNT(PC.CategoryID) AS ProductCount
    FROM ProductCategoryRelation PC
    WHERE PC.CategoryID IN (1,2,3)
    GROUP BY PC.ProductID
    HAVING COUNT(PC.CategoryID) = 3
)
SELECT *
FROM Product
    INNER JOIN CTE_ProductCount PC ON PC.ProductID = Product.ProductID;
```